# How to register two classes that inherit from IdentityUser with different DbContexts (ASP.NET Core 6 Web API)

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

I want to use `builder.Services.AddIdentity()` as follows:

- `User` and `Employee` classes inherit from `IdentityUser`.
- `AppDbContext` and `EmployeeDbContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext`.

As you might have guessed, `Users` and `Employees` are stored in different databases and they have different properties (that's why I didn't want to use the role feature). I want to be able to use `UserManager<User>` and `UserManager<Employee>` so I can't handle logic of both types in the same method and make complex logic.

But this here does not work. When I run the API project I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'

Apparently an ASP.NET Core Web API doesn't support registering `AddIdentity` twice. Do you have a solution for my use case?

I want to use ASP.NET Core Identity for 2 different `IdentityUser` in 2 different databases in the same application.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>>("name1")
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<Employee, IdentityRole>()        
    .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<Employee>>("name2")        
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EmployeeDbContext>()   
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {     
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;       
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters     
                                            {
                                                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,       
                                                ValidateIssuer = true,         
                                                ValidateAudience = true,
                                                ValidateLifetime = true,          
                                                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,         
                                                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],         builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:IssuerEmployees"] },         
                                                ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],       
                                                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Key"]))     
                                            }; 
});
```

Someone has suggested the following: "you can multiple providers, but they each need a unique authentication scheme (name), that is you can not use the default for both. you will also need to define authentication polices because you are not using the default setup."

But I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need two identity for different identity dbcontext?

Comment: @BrandoZhang because I am using two different classes that inherit from IdentityUser and im storing them in 2 databases.